# robot_localization ignores pose data input

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, robot-localization, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
My system description is as follows:
Turtlebot - ros-kinetic - Ubuntu 16.04

I am running two instances of robot_localization, odometry in the first instance and 'odometry and global pose' in the second.

1. odom--> base_footprint (this is my equivalent of base_link). I'm adding a high noise (std_dev = 1) to the /odom and publishing it as /odom_noisy :
   frequency: 100
   two_d_mode: true

   map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified

   odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified

   base_link_frame: base_footprint  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified

   world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

   odom0: /odom_noisy

   odom0_config: [false, false,  false,
   false, false, false,
   true, true, false,
   false, false, true,
   false, false, false]
   odom0_queue_size: 5
   odom0_nodelay: false
   odom0_differential: false
   odom0_relative: false

   use_control: true

   ## Whether the input (assumed to be cmd_vel) is a geometry_msgs/Twist or geometry_msgs/TwistStamped message. Defaults to

   ## false.

   stamped_control: false

   ## The last issued control command will be used in prediction for this period. Defaults to 0.2.

   control_timeout: 0.1

   ## Which velocities are being controlled. Order is vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw.

   control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]

   ## Places limits on how large the acceleration term will be. Should match your robot's kinematics.

   acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]

   ## Acceleration and deceleration limits are not always the same for robots.

   deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]

   ## If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its acceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these

   ## gains

   acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]

   ## If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its deceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these

   ## gains

   deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
   process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0.5, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.005, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.04, 0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

   ## [ADVANCED] This represents the initial value for the state estimate error covariance matrix. Setting a diagonal

   ## value (variance) to a large value will result in rapid convergence for initial measurements of the variable in

   ## question. Users should take care not to use large values for variables that will not be measured directly. The values

   ## are ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the matrix below

   #if unspecified.
   initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-2, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    1e-2, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
2. map-> base_footprint (or map-> odom). The pose data (which is the global absolute orientation) has a std_dev of .01 degrees. Given a high level of accuracy in pose data and very noisy /odom_noisy, I expect the EKF to almost completely trust the pose data and output reasonably accurate data. What I'm seeing is a highly oscillating (especially the yaw) output, similar to that of /odom_noisy. As such, removing /abs_orientation doesn't seem to make any difference. The corresponding yaml file is as follows:

   frequency: 100

   two_d_mode: true

   map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
   odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
   base_link_frame: base_footprint  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
   world_frame: map           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified
   odom0: /odom_noisy
   odom0_config: [false, false,  false,
   false, false, false,
   true, true, false,
   false, false, true,
   false, false, false]
   odom0_queue_size: 5
   odom0_nodelay: false
   odom0_differential: false
   odom0_relative: false

   pose0: abs_orientation
   pose0_config: [false, false,  false,
   false, false, true,
   false, false, false,
   false, false, false,
   false, false, false]
   pose0_differential: false
   pose0_relative: false
   pose0_queue_size: 5

   pose0_rejection_threshold: 2  # Note the difference in parameter name
   pose0_nodelay: false

   use_control: true

   ## Whether the input (assumed to be cmd_vel) is a geometry_msgs/Twist or geometry_msgs/TwistStamped message. Defaults to

   ## false.

   stamped_control: false

   ## The last issued control command will be used in prediction for this period. Defaults to 0.2.

   control_timeout: 0.1

   ## Which velocities are being controlled. Order is vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw.

   control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]

   ## Places limits on how large the acceleration term will be. Should match your robot's kinematics.

   acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]

   ## Acceleration and deceleration limits are not always the same for robots.

   deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]

   ## If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its acceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these

   ## gains

   acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]

   ## If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its deceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these

   ## gains

   deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

   process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0.5, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.005, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.05, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.04, 0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

   ## [ADVANCED] This represents the initial value for the state estimate error covariance matrix. Setting a diagonal

   ## value (variance) to a large value will result in rapid convergence for initial measurements of the variable in

   ## question. Users should take care not to use large values for variables that will not be measured directly. The values

   ## are ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the matrix below

   #if unspecified.
   initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-2, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    1e-2, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]

Below are the outputs:

1. /odometry_map/filtered - published by the second instance robot_localization

   header:
   seq: 5253
   stamp:
   secs: 760
   nsecs: 663000000
   frame_id: "map"
   child_frame_id: "base_footprint"
   pose:
   pose:
   position:
   x: 0.0442575591845
   y: 0.0155869558694
   z: 0.0
   orientation:
   x: 0.0
   y: 0.0
   z: 0.384538862254
   w: 0.923108803672
   covariance: [2.663882074729417, 0.0008610832095776304, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.026921653227594575, 0.0008610832095776344, 2.6635865448664076, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.026110560973774358, 0.0, 0.0, 9.993342210219859e-07, 6.797855885527078e-16, 4.2373098980630226e-16, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.797855885527075e-16, 9.934210138929739e-07, -4.326463119371932e-22, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.2373098980630226e-16, -4.326463124267019e-22, 9.934210138929745e-07, 0.0, 0.026921653227594475, 0.026110560973774316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9468182423951728]
   twist:
   twist:
   linear:
   x: 0.0101380887639
   y: 0.0387535834841
   z: 0.0
   angular:
   x: 0.0
   y: 0.0
   z: -0.0794096879414
   covariance: [0.0009540229033699445, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0009540229033699445, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.934210328992857e-07, 3.0421620013966033e-25, -6.746667100726666e-26, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0421620013966033e-25, 9.934210325162797e-07, 7.921164614905649e-32, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -6.746667100726666e-26, 7.9257534448641e-32, 9.934210325162797e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.023089536420008897]
2. /odometry/filtered

   header:
   seq: 5215
   stamp:
   secs: 760
   nsecs: 297000000
   frame_id: "odom"
   child_frame_id: "base_footprint"
   pose:
   pose:
   position:
   x: 0.0481059004207
   y: 0.0277482869621
   z: 0.0
   orientation:
   x: 0.0
   y: 0.0
   z: 0.477356029252
   w: 0.878709975667
   covariance: [2.644794104685194, 0.0007909579721065899, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.017066758856500826, 0.0007909579721065879, 2.645671616728246, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03529150350258051, 0.0, 0.0, 9.995004994888809e-07, 5.3017097166727106e-17, 1.6334620670616377e-16, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.3017097166727094e-17, 9.95049485090448e-07, -1.7337851303703824e-23, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.633462067061637e-16, -1.733785070966406e-23, 9.95049485090448e-07, 0.0, 0.017066758856500774, 0.03529150350258047, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9383404560967562]
   twist:
   twist:
   linear:
   x: -0.0149190117811
   y: -0.0123008162423
   z: 0.0
   angular:
   x: 0.0
   y: 0.0
   z: -0.0450499681531
   covariance: [0.000921183130561197, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000921183130561197, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.950494900372747e-07, 6.507436387617446e-26, 1.682587054280008e-26, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.507436387617443e-26, 9.950494896505053e-07, -5.429910242222473e-33, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.682587054280008e-26, -5.82064332144405e-33, 9.950494896505053e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.022759494263694245]
3. /abs_orientation

   header:
   seq: 552
   stamp:
   secs: 0
   nsecs:         0
   frame_id: "world"
   pose:
   pose:
   position:
   x: 0.0
   y: 0.0
   z: 0.0
   orientation:
   x: 0.0
   y: 0.0
   z: 0.000459218843978
   w: 0.999999894559
   covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.046174061692489e-08]

Edit-1 :

There is a static_transform from world to map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288603/robot_localization-ignores-pose-data-input/) by [Karthikeya Parunandi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25315/karthikeya-parunandi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2018-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `abs_orientation` message has a `frame_id` of *world*. Are you providing a static transform to convert that to *map*? If the EKF can't transform the input data to *map*, *odom*, or *base_footprint*, it can't use it.

Also, you should turn on `two_d_mode`. I'd also turn off control as an input until you get the rest working.

EDIT: your time stamps in `abs_orientation` are also not filled out. Time stamps matter to the state estimation nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karthikeya Parunandi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25315/karthikeya-parunandi/) on 2018-04-13**:
Yes, I have a static transform from `map` to `world`. The `two_d_mode` is also on (Sorry, forgot to copy that in the question). Updated now. Switching off the control doesn't make any difference too. Is there anything more that I could do? Thanks!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-04-13**:
Edited my response.

**Comment by [Karthikeya Parunandi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25315/karthikeya-parunandi/) on 2018-04-13**:
Filling the time stamps did the trick. Thanks a lot!